# MySQL query with multiple joins, selecting based on joined type

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure how to write a query that meets these criteria:

```
SELECT
    gems.*, metals.*

FROM
    `locations`

JOIN
    gems ON locations.locatable_id = gems.id AND locations.locatable_type = 'Gem'

JOIN
    metals ON locations.locatable_id = metals.id AND locations.locatable_type = 'Metal'

WHERE
    locations.latitude BETWEEN 0.0000 AND 1.0000 AND locations.longitude BETWEEN -1.0000 AND -2.0000
```

Where the result will SELECT some `gems` if the associated `locations` result from the WHERE statement is of locatable_type `Gem`, and SELECT `metals` if the `locations` is of type `Metal`.

Is it possible to have a mixed result like that?

Comment: add sample data and desired result That will help to understand your question

Comment: You should do two separate JOIN queries, and combine them with `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` with `locations` table twice as `locations.locatable_type` can't be both 'Gem' and 'Metal' at the same time e.g.:

```
SELECT
    gems.*, metals.*

FROM
    `locations` l1

JOIN
    gems ON l1.locatable_id = gems.id AND l1.locatable_type = 'Gem'

JOIN
    users ON locations.locatable_id = metals.id AND locations.locatable_type = 'Metal'

WHERE
    l1.latitude BETWEEN 0.0000 AND 1.0000 AND l1.longitude BETWEEN -1.0000 AND -2.0000



UNION



SELECT
    gems.*, metals.*

FROM
    `locations` l=2

JOIN
    users ON l2.locatable_id = metals.id AND l2.locatable_type = 'Metal'

WHERE
    l2.latitude BETWEEN 0.0000 AND 1.0000 AND l2.longitude BETWEEN -1.0000 AND -2.0000
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to restructure your query a bit. The following should work...

```
SELECT 
    G.*, M.*
FROM
    locations L
        JOIN
    gems G ON L.locatable_id = G.id
        JOIN
    metals M ON L.locatable_id = M.id
WHERE
    L.latitude BETWEEN 0.0000 AND 1.0000
        AND L.longitude BETWEEN - 1.0000 AND - 2.0000
        AND (L.locatable_type = 'Gem' OR L.locatable_type = 'Metal');
```